# How can I click a link using HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

```
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
        var inputForms = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input");
        var hrefLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
        foreach(HtmlNode input in inputForms)
        {
            if(input.OuterHtml.Contains("SUBMIT-chn:$INTERNAL_password.pss"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Found It");
                // I would like to do something like
                // input.Click();
                // then the newly navigatedPage would be reprocessed
            }
        }
```

Instead of my messagebox, I want to click the input and navigate to the new page.

I am stuck here so any help would be appreciated. I am avoiding the use of WebBrowser control or msHtml

Comment: No way using HtmlAgilityPack. HAP doesn't emulate browser behavior, so it's unable to run js nor provide a way for you to interact with the HTML (like clicking on a button)

Comment: So is there another way to click the button without using the built in browser control?